# PyQt5 run the slot for default combobox selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have created a QComboBox (let's call it QC1) which populates another QComboBox (QC2) which in-turn creates a groupbox.

I want to activate the slot for default items of both QC1 and QC2 initially and that of QC2 when QC1 is changed. I have tried searching throughout the web and here to no avail.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.vBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.QC1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.QC1.addItems(['C1-Op1','C1-Op2'])
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.QC1)

        self.QC2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.QC2.addItem('')
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.QC2)            
        self.QC1.activated[str].connect(self.QC1_activate)

        self.gBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.vBox_gB = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.gBox)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.vBox)


    def QC1_activate(self,text):
        self.QC2.clear()
        dic={'C1-Op1':'C2-Op1','C1-Op2':'C2-Op2'}
        self.QC2.addItem(dic[text])
        self.QC2.activated[str].connect(self.QC2_activate)

    def QC2_activate(self,text):
        self.clearLayout(self,self.vBox_gB)
        lbl = QLabel(text) 
        self.vBox_gB.addWidget(lbl)
        self.gBox.setLayout(self.vBox_gB)


    @staticmethod
    def clearLayout(self, layout):
        if layout is not None:
            while layout.count():
                item = layout.takeAt(0)
                widget = item.widget()
                if widget is not None:
                    widget.deleteLater()
                else:
                    self.clearLayout(item.layout())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above is literally the most minimal working example I could come up with

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I understood correctly, you want to get the history of the activated `QC2` elements in `QGroupBox`.

I did not understand why the static method `clearLayout` is needed.

Try the example below, maybe it will push you to new ideas.

```
import sys
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget,
                             QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QApplication, QGroupBox)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()               
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.QC1  = QComboBox(self)
        self.QC1.addItems(['C1-Op1', 'C1-Op2'])
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.QC1)

        self.QC2 = QComboBox()                  
        #self.QC2.addItem('')
        self.QC2.addItem('Some element popup list')
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.QC2)  

        self.QC1.activated[str].connect(self.QC1_activate)
        self.QC2.activated[str].connect(self.QC2_activate)   # +++

        self.gBox    = QGroupBox(" * QGroupBox * ")
        self.vBox_gB = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.gBox)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.vBox)

    def QC1_activate(self, text):
        #self.QC2.clear()
        dic = {'C1-Op1':'C2-Op1','C1-Op2':'C2-Op2'}
        #self.QC2.addItem(dic[text])

        # +++
        if self.QC2.count() == 1:
            self.QC2.addItem(dic[text])
        else:
            self.QC2.setItemText(1, dic[text])

        #self.QC2.activated[str].connect(self.QC2_activate)  

    def QC2_activate(self, text):
        #self.clearLayout(self, self.vBox_gB) 
        lbl = QLabel(text) 
        self.vBox_gB.addWidget(lbl)
        self.gBox.setLayout(self.vBox_gB)

    #@staticmethod                   ???
    #def clearLayout(self, layout):  ??? 
    # ...      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @S. Nick, Thanks for the reply. I don't want the history at all. The method clearLayout clears the layout to remove the QLabel lbl. In absence of that, (as we can see in your suggested solution), the old items are still displayed. What I actually want it that as soon as I set C1-Op2 as the default item, C2-Op2 is immediately selected, which in-turn triggers self.QC2_activate immediately to display in the label. IRL there are multiple groups of radio buttons for each option in QC2, so can't have the old ones present when option is changed.

Answer (score 0):

This entire project could be simplified a lot (I don't see why you use dicts into comboboxes, but whatever). I think what you want is:

```
self.QC2.addItem(dic[text]) # Your code
self.QC2.activated[str].connect(self.QC2_activate) # Your code
self.QC2.setCurrentText(dic[text]) # New code
```

That last line sets up the current text for the combo. I can't test it at the moment, but activated should trigger after that. If it doesn't, then you can just change the trigger from `activated` to something like `currentTextChanged` which definitely should work.